# Visual Studio does not recognize global.json

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2015, asp.net-core

It seems Visual Studio doesn't recognize .NET Core `global.json` which list `src` and `test` as the projects in the solution. Without the famous `.sln` file, each project in the solution can be opened individually by opening associated `project.json`. Is there a way to open a solution which load the two projects?

Comment: In my experience, if you refer to a project in `project.json` (using target=project) then if it can be found using `global.json`, the project is automatically added to the solution. Can you give more details about what you're trying to achieve?

Comment: @Jon just following along the guide here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/articles/core/testing/unit-testing-with-dotnet-test. Only to find, I can't just open the created solution and continue in visual studio.

Comment: Just create an empty solution file, and then you can add existing projects to that. The `global.json` file isn't really a solution file - it just says where tools should look for projects.

Comment: I see. Just out of interest, shouldn't that cause problems, if say, we are working on the same project with other team members using non-windows machine? Here I take `.sln` is visual studio specific.

Comment: No, it won't cause any problems - it just specifies projects to edit/build together. You should be able to build from the command line equally well.

Comment: Hm. Just noted something interesting. If I open test `project.json`, the src project is automatically loaded (I guess because test project references src). But the interesting part is as soon as I close the solution, VS prompt to save changes to `myproject.sln` (or  `myproject.Test.sln`, whichever project I opened) which never existed in the first place.

Comment: Solution is the top level project container in VS, even if you open JUST a project it will want to create a sln for it. In memory it already created a solution to load the project into.

Comment: just use VS 2017, it use solutions and projects as before without these jsons.

Comment: Does that mean we should expect backward incompatibility  in vs 2017?  The jsons are still cool I must say. I Iike it when you can add dependencies in the json with some intellisense. The only other turn off is when VS doesn't see solution folders.

Comment: So far, VS 2017 is not ready for use with .net core yet, it's a mess.  Migration from .xproj back to .csproj is a disaster.

Comment: VS 2017 works fine with .NET Core, it just uses .csproj instead .xpro and json